# How to add padding to Illustrator document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

I have an 11x17 poster that

- Will have 3/16 white border (because the printer can't print to the edge)
- needs 3/16 padding from edge for all objects

I don't want to print it on 12x18 and cut it so right now I have it set up as a 10.625x16.625 with all-around 0.1875 bleed and I also want to have a line showing 0.1875 padding (or at least in the web world we call it padding).

1. What's the **name designer's use** for the **space between the printed edge and the objects** inside (css calls it padding)?
2. Should I just **add that with four guides**? Or is there something part of **document setup** (like **bleed** and **slug**) that will give me a preset border / guide?

I don't yet think like a designer so I'm probably thinking about the problem in a weird way, but I've got all of about 10 hours of illustrator use under my belt so be kind.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be called 'margin' or 'white space'. You'd typically set it up by using crop/registration marks--which if you set your document up to the printed size, Illustrator should be able to accomodate when you print.